# C, function too long for the norm

Tags: c, function

I need your help please.

First of all, this is not an exercice I'll have a grade for, it comes from a programming school but I'm doing it only in order to train. So helping me will not be unethical :)

I'm trying to do an exercise (called `ft_print_comb`). My function is supposed to do this:

```
$ ./a.exe | cat -e
012, 013, 014, 015, 016, 017, 018, 019, 023, 024, 025, 026, 027, 028, 029, 034, 035, 036, 037, 038, 039, 045, 046, 047, 048, 049, 056, 057, 058, 059, 067, 068, 069, 078, 079, 089, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 156, 157, 158, 159, 167, 168, 169, 178, 179, 189, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 256, 257, 258, 259, 267, 268, 269, 278, 279, 289, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 356, 357, 358, 359, 367, 368, 369, 378, 379, 389, 456, 457, 458, 459, 467, 468, 469, 478, 479, 489, 567, 568, 569, 578, 579, 589, 678, 679, 689, 789
$
```

basicaly it shows every number between 000 to 999 if the combination of three numbers within did not already appear. For instance there's no 978 as 7, 8 and 9 already appeared in 789.

I wrote something that already works, that looks like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>


void            ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write ( 1, &c, 1);
}

void            ft_print_comb(void)
{
    int     a;
    int     b;
    int     c;

    a = 0;

    while (a < 8)
    {
            b = a + 1;
            while (b < 9)
            {
                    c = b + 1;
                    while (c <= 9)
                    {
                            ft_putchar('0' + a%10);
                            ft_putchar('0' + b%10);
                            ft_putchar('0' + c%10);
                            if (a < 7 || b < 8 || c < 9)
                            {
                                    ft_putchar(',');
                                    ft_putchar(' ');
                            }
                            c++;
                    }
                    b++;
            }
            a++;
    }
    ft_putchar('\n');
}


int             main()
{
    ft_print_comb();
    return(0);
}
```

But the thing is, I have quite a strict norm to follow (Epitech's norm):
 - I'm not allowed to use any function from the librairies but write (and write will only be used for ft_putchar) (no printf);
 - I'm not allowed to use 'for';
 - I'm not allowed to either write 'int a, b, c = 0' or ft_putchar(a, b, c), it has to be as I wrote it (meaning rewrite ft_putchar on a new line every time for instance);
 - My function must be 25 lines long maximum.
 - My function called in the main must be void ft_print_comb(void);
 - I can have up to 5 functions.

That's pretty much it. This exercice is given the first day people study C language in this school, so in theory I don't need more than loops and incrementation, but I've tried for hours to have a 25 lines function and I feel like it's out of my reach. I thought about dividing the function in other functions that I would call in my 'void  ft_print_comb(void)' but this is not something I master enough yet (I'm quite a newbee here).

Anyway thanks for your help and your time, and sorry for my far from being perfect English.

(Edit)
I did it, thanks to your answers. This is what it looks like:

```
#include <unistd.h>


void            ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write ( 1, &c, 1);
}

void            ft_printabc(int a, int b, int c)
{
    ft_putchar('0' + a%10);
    ft_putchar('0' + b%10);
    ft_putchar('0' + c%10);
    if (a < 7 || b < 8 || c < 9)
    {
            ft_putchar(',');
            ft_putchar(' ');
    }
}

void            ft_print_comb(void)
{
    int     a;
    int     b;
    int     c;

    a = 0;

    while (a < 8)
    {
            b = a + 1;
            while (b < 9)
            {
                    c = b + 1;
                    while (c <= 9)
                    {
                            ft_printabc(a, b, c);
                            c++;
                    }
                    b++;
            }
            a++;
    }
    ft_putchar('\n');
}


int             main()
{
    ft_print_comb();
    return(0);
}
```

I don't know if you understood I was allowed to do this, explaining the norm was quite hard in a language that is not my native one. At the end of the day it is far less complicated than what we were looking for, but your comments helped me out alot (let's say I have a few notions in C, but not much).

Again, thank you every one.

Comment: You can collapse lines, C doesn't mind: `} c++; } b++; } a++; } ft_putchar('\n'); } int main() {`

Comment: Yes but "they" do. The norm doesnt allow this either. 
The goal of their norm is to have the most readable code possible, therefore crushing lines is forbiden.

Comment: Even though this is the only way I see, I must admit.

Comment: I would think that if this "Epitech's Norm" is really a thing, I could get search better results than just finding this question. Also, how is `while` better than `for`?

Comment: IMO, this would be much more readable, if you were allowed to use `for` loops. But maybe that's just me =)

Comment: Yeah I know, there's a great argument about that. I don't make these rules, I know why they are made, but as to if they're legit I'm far from being good enough to have a real opinion. I'm just following them :/ 
I tried to find a pdf with the norm, but it's kept "inside" the school. I know it though, but I forget to tell some of these rules, and I'm sorry about that.

Comment: I'm good enough to have a real opinion, and I think most of these rules are incredibly stupid. I get the pedagogical value of some of them, but “no comments”, “whitespace lines count”, “no initialization on declaration”? These are the opposite of good practice.

Comment: Well this is the global norm. But in the other hand, when I used it was when I was first introduced to C language. They might alow other ways to write later on. Maybe is it only in order to prevent begginers from getting lost. I don't know.

Comment: Wait, does Epitech really forbid *comments*? I can see what they are coming from ("If you need comments, your code isn't readable enough") but that's stupid. Some rules also make the code *less* readable, because while it's hard to read a function that doesn't fit a TTY screen, it's harder to read **ravioli code** (and it actually causes *more* scrolling).

Answer (score 6):

By getting rid of `ft_putchar` and using a recursive helper function, I did it :)

```
/* 01 */ #include <unistd.h>
/* 02 */
/* 03 */ void ft_helper(int a, int b, int c) {
/* 04 */     if (a == 10) return;
/* 05 */     else if (b == 10) ft_helper(a + 1, a + 2, a + 3);
/* 06 */     else if (c == 10) ft_helper(a, b + 1, b + 2);
/* 07 */     else {
/* 08 */         write(1, ", ", 2);
/* 09 */         write(1, "0123456789" + a, 1);
/* 10 */         write(1, "0123456789" + b, 1);
/* 11 */         write(1, "0123456789" + c, 1);
/* 12 */         ft_helper(a, b, c + 1);
/* 13 */     }
/* 14 */ }
/* 15 */
/* 16 */ void ft_print_comb(void) {
/* 17 */     write(1, "012", 3);
/* 18 */     ft_helper(0, 1, 3);
/* 19 */     write(1, "\n", 1);
/* 20 */ }
/* 21 */
/* 22 */ int main(void) {
/* 23 */     ft_print_comb();
/* 24 */     return 0;
/* 25 */ }
```

25 lines in total (counting blank lines)

Comment: I'm not allowed to get rid of ft_putchar. I'm going to edit the main post. I have to use write to create my putchar, but I cant use it elsewhere :/

Comment: I give up then! Glad I don't have to code to such tight requirements.

Comment: Haha I understand, thank you anyway, it'll be of a great help when I come to work on recursive functions :)

Comment: This said your function can be up to 25 lines, but your programm can be longer if you want to :)

Comment: @pmg: +1 for a nice solution. Pity about the constantly-changing irrational rules :)

Comment: The stupid rules are allegedly for readability; this code is the *least* readable. @Emmet: They're not constantly changing, Komott just failed to disclose them in one go.

Answer (score 3):

You're working under an arbitrary set of artificial constraints that we don't know.

The rules, as I understand them now, are:

1. There may not be more than one statement per line
2. Braces must be on a line of their own
3. Variables must be declared and initialized on separate lines
4. You must use `while` for iteration, not `for` statements
5. No library function other than `stdlib.h:write()` may be called
6. You must implement the functionality in a function called `ft_print_comb()`
7. Up to 5 functions may be defined
8. No function may exceed 25 lines in length
9. Empty lines count
10. Lines containing only braces count
11. Comments are prohibited (!)

To be as conservative (verbose!) as possible, I have assumed the following rule that is not explicitly stated:

1. `if`s must use braces (on a line of their own)

I've edited this a few times because I was playing with it. This one seems to work, and follows my current understanding of the rules.

The innermost `if` in the original code is unnecessary if you adapt the loop bounds.

I have defined `ft_puts()`, a local equivalent to `stdio:puts()`, and removed `ft_putchar()`.

Following a suggestion from *chux*, I removed the separate variables for digits and conversion from integers to characters.

```
void ft_puts(char *s)
{
    char *p;
    p = s;
    while( *(p++) != '\0' )
        ;
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, s, (p-s));
}                                              // 8 lines


void ft_print_comb(void) 
{
    char digit[6];                             // ="/--, " breaks Rule 3.
    digit[0] = '0'-1;
    digit[3] = ',';
    digit[4] = ' ';
    digit[5] = '\0';
    while (digit[0]++ < '7') 
    {
        digit[1] = digit[0];
        while (digit[1]++ < '8') 
        {
            digit[2]=digit[1];
            while (digit[2]++ < '9') 
            {
                if( digit[0]=='7' && digit[1]=='8' && digit[2]=='9' ) 
                {
                    digit[3] = '\n';
                }
                ft_puts(digit);
            }
        }
    }
}                                              // 24 lines
```

If you flat out ignore the sillier rules, you can do it pretty readably in 15 lines:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void) {
    char digit[6] = "/--, ";
    while (digit[0]++ < '7') {
        digit[1] = digit[0];
        while (digit[1]++ < '8') {
            digit[2]=digit[1];
            while (digit[2]++ < '9') {
                if( digit[0]=='7' && digit[1]=='8' && digit[2]=='9' )
                    digit[3] = '\n';
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, digit, 5);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only the write of the `", "` is going to work.  All the others are passing a `char` where a `char*` is required

Comment: Fair point. Fixed. I'm not sure I haven't introduced one or more off-by-1 errors either. I'm more trying to get at whether a solution along these lines breaks the stupid rules or not.

Comment: I'd have to write int a; and a = 0; on diffrent lines. I'd also have to skip a line every time I open a bracket.
This said, it seems it might do the trick, I'll try this and tell you.

Comment: @Komott: I doubt it produces the output that you want (I haven't tested it), but you get the idea, I'm sure. How are lines counted? Do comments count? Lines with just a curly bracket?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use "write" alone, sorry I forgot. I have to use "ft_putchar" (I'm allowed to use write only in order to create an ft_putchar function).

Sorry I thought I said it but I didn't. Quite hard to summ up all the rules of the norm.

But I think it might help anyway. Brb.

@ Emmet: Lines are counted from the title of the function to the last bracket.

Comment: Doesn't work. Still longer than 25 lines when I put it to the norm, and I get:
$ ./a.exe | cat -e
123, 124, 125, 126, ... , 589, 580, 590, 678, 679, 670, 689, 680, 690, 789, 780, 790, 890$"

Comment: So at the end of the day, in order to follow the norm and be back to the result I want, I end up with my original code. Thanks anyway, and sorry, I know this must not be a thrilling exercice for you :)

Comment: @Komott: Do empty lines count? Do lines with comments count? Do lines containing only braces count? Does the definition of `ft_putchar` (the stupidest function I have ever heard of, it just duplicatea `putchar` from `stdio`) count?

Comment: @Komott: Can you have as many functions as you like provided none of them are longer than 25 lines? Is that the constraint? That makes a huge difference!

Comment: @Emmet Empty lines count as a line;
Line with only a brace count as a line;
I'm not allowed by the norm to have comments lines;
You can have up to five functions including ft_print_comb.

You understood the rest of the norm very well.

Comment: @Emmet It works!
I think there must be a way without using pointers, as the exercice is in a "loop" set of exercices, but it works and that's what matters. 
Thank you alot, even though I'll have to figure a way out in order to use putchar and not "write" alone, but that I can do (I guess). Thanks for your time and your efforts every one!

Comment: Also, I'm not quiete sure I'm allowed to use a buffer that way, but it trained me alot anyway. I'll keep you in touch.

Comment: I also get a comma after "789". I'll have to think this through.

Comment: +1 Nice.  Minor:  Why the `%10`, seems unneeded.  `char buf[6] = "___, ";` could be `char buf[] = "___, ";`

Comment: @chux: Right on both counts. I just wanted to be as explicit as possible with the declaration and never really gave any thought to the `%10`.

Comment: Pestering additional comment.  Use `buf[0]` for `a`, etc. and offset math to '0' rather than 0.  Rather than `a = -1;`, `buf[0] = '0' -1;`.

Answer (score 1):

I know Epitech from reputation.

Can't you just split the function?

```
#include <unistd.h>


void ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write ( STDOUT_FILENO, &c, 1); /*Magic numbers are evil*/
}

void ft_print_inner(int a, int b, int c)
{
    ft_putchar('0' + a%10);
    ft_putchar('0' + b%10);
    ft_putchar('0' + c%10);
    if (a < 7 || b < 8 || c < 9)
    {
        ft_putchar(',');
        ft_putchar(' ');
    }
}

void ft_print_comb(void)
{
    int     a;
    int     b;
    int     c;

    a = 0;

    while (a < 8);
    {
        b = a + 1;
        while (b < 9)
        {
            c = b + 1;
            while (c <= 9)
            {
                ft_print_inner(a, b, c);
                c++:
            }
            b++;
        }
        a++;
    }
    ft_putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: So is it that you can have as many functions as you like provide none of them is longer than 25 lines? That makes a big difference!

Comment: Doesn't work, but this is something I wanted to do. But as I said, I'm far from being good (yet!) so I didnt see how to do it. 
Anyway when I gcc -Werror -Wextra -Wall my_file.c I get no error, but all I get afterward is: 
$ ./a.exe | cat -e

Comment: @Emmet Yes I'm allowed to, as I said "only the other functions from the librairies are forbiden", but I'm allowed to have up to 5 functions of my own (not counting int main() ) as long as they do not use forbiden fonctions, such as "printf" for instance.

Comment: +1 for `STDOUT_FILENO`. I've updated my own answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is really silly, and it probably violates the spirit of the exercise, but is this one-liner legal?

```
#include <unistd.h>

char *a = "012, 013, 014, 015, 016, 017, 018, 019, 023, 024, 025, 026, 027, 028, 029, 034, 035, 036, 037, 038, 039, 045, 046, 047, 048, 049, 056, 057, 058, 059, 067, 068, 069, 078, 079, 089, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 156, 157, 158, 159, 167, 168, 169, 178, 179, 189, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 256, 257, 258, 259, 267, 268, 269, 278, 279, 289, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 356, 357, 358, 359, 367, 368, 369, 378, 379, 389, 456, 457, 458, 459, 467, 468, 469, 478, 479, 489, 567, 568, 569, 578, 579, 589, 678, 679, 689, 789\n";

void ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write ( 1, &c, 1);
}

void ft_print_comb(void)
{
    while(*a) ft_putchar(*a++);
}
```

Comment: Haha no I'm not allowed to do this. The programm has to find it by its own means.
Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's another version based on my first attempt.

Total number of lines: 32
blank and #include lines: 5
lines for `main`: 4
lines for `ft_putchar`: 3

rest of lines: `32 - 5 - 4 - 3` = 20

lines for `ft_helper`: 13
lines for `ft_print_comb`: 7
total lines for "personal" functions: 20

```
/* 01 */ #include <unistd.h>
/* 02 */
/* 03 */ void ft_putchar(char c) {
/* 04 */     write(1, &c, 1);
/* 05 */ }
/* 06 */
/* 07 */ void ft_helper(int a, int b, int c) {
/* 08 */     if (a == 10) return;
/* 09 */     else if (b == 10) ft_helper(a + 1, a + 2, a + 3);
/* 10 */     else if (c == 10) ft_helper(a, b + 1, b + 2);
/* 11 */     else {
/* 12 */         ft_putchar(',');
/* 13 */         ft_putchar(' ');
/* 14 */         ft_putchar("0123456789"[a]);
/* 15 */         ft_putchar("0123456789"[b]);
/* 16 */         ft_putchar("0123456789"[c]);
/* 17 */         ft_helper(a, b, c + 1);
/* 18 */     }
/* 19 */ }
/* 20 */
/* 21 */ void ft_print_comb(void) {
/* 22 */     ft_putchar('0');
/* 23 */     ft_putchar('1');
/* 24 */     ft_putchar('2');
/* 25 */     ft_helper(0, 1, 3);
/* 26 */     ft_putchar('\n');
/* 27 */ }
/* 28 */
/* 29 */ int main(void) {
/* 30 */     ft_print_comb();
/* 31 */     return 0;
/* 32 */ }
```